# How to use paperclip with one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

How would I go about using only one column to represent all four paperclip attributes?

- _file_name
- _file_size
- _content_type
- _updated_at

I'm testing with only the file_name attribute, because that's all that paperclip requires, and storing all my data in a value column on Field, which FileField Inherits. I was thinking I could just overwrite the file_name reading and writing, but that isn't working.

```
#model
class FileField < Field
  has_attached_file :logo
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :logo
  def logo_file_name=(file_name)
    if file_name.present?
      @value = file_name
    end
  end
  def logo_file_name
    @value
  end


#form
= f.input :logo, as: :file
```

**Update**
My syntax was wrong, I was able to get it working with the following

```
has_attached_file :attachment


validates_attachment :attachment, presence: true,
  content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/png"] },
  size: { in: 0..15.kilobytes }
def attachment_file_name=(file_name)
  if file_name.present?
    self.value = "#{file_name},#{attachment_content_type},#{attachment_file_size},#{attachment_updated_at}"
  end
end
def attachment_file_name
  self.value.to_s.split(",").first
end
def attachment_content_type=(content_type)
  if content_type.present?
    self.value = "#{attachment_file_name},#{content_type},#{attachment_file_size},#{attachment_updated_at}"
  end
end
def attachment_content_type
  self.value.to_s.split(",").second
end
def attachment_file_size=(file_size)
  self.value = "#{attachment_file_name},#{attachment_content_type},#{file_size},#{attachment_updated_at}"
end
def attachment_file_size
  self.value.to_s.split(",").third.to_i unless self.value.to_s.split(",").third.blank?
end
def attachment_updated_at=(value)
  self.value = "#{attachment_file_name},#{attachment_content_type},#{attachment_file_size},#{value}"
end
def attachment_updated_at
  self.value.to_s.split(",").fourth
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but it's work a try:

```
class FileField < Field
  attr_accessor :logo_file_size, :logo_content_type, :logo_updated_at
  has_attached_file :logo
  ...
end
```

The idea is to trick paperclip into thinking that there are those attributes available, and not caring what values are returned.

Comment: no such luck, though I'm not sure where it's going wrong. With my code above I'm getting no changes, but when i explicitly set self.value = @value, It saves values of logo (i.e it has a url and other paperclip attributes), but it cannot find the file. I'm not sure how paperclip is saving the files and how to use that

Comment: Probably your best bet is to just add the extra columns. I know you don't need the information, but is it really going to cause a problem? Maybe better to just bite the bullet and add the extra columns.

Comment: The problem is that the columns would be added to a table used for STI in a gem, so all fields inherited from it in the gem would have nil for all paperclip columns. It's not ideal, but it is the only solution I've gotten to work so far.